# Go empty interface type assertion and creating a copy

Tags: go

Can't figure out how to modify a struct type variable passed as pointer to a function that takes in an empty interface

I am creating a kind of library that works with MongoDB database through official go driver. I am passing a struct pointer which then gets filled with data from database (MongoDB `cursor.Decode`). This works fine for a single document, but when I try to return an array of documents, only the parent documents are correct, but children(embedded) stay same for all the elements in array (probably store reference and not the actual value).

Actual code:

```golang
// passing model pointer to search function
result, _ := mongodb.Search(&store.Time{}, 
                mongodb.D{mongodb.E("transdate", 
                    mongodb.D{mongodb.E("$gte", timeSearch.DateFrom), mongodb.E("$lte", timeSearch.DateTo)})})

...
func Search(model interface{}, filter interface{}) (result ModelCollection, err error) {
    collection := Database.Collection(resolveCollectionName(model))

    var cursor *mongo.Cursor
    cursor, err = collection.Find(Context, filter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } 

    for cursor.Next(Context) {
        if err := cursor.Decode(model); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        modelDeref := reflect.ValueOf(model).Elem().Interface()
        result = append(result, modelDeref)
    }

    return
}
```

Here is the closest playground example I could come up with. I replaced MongoDB `cursor.Decode()` with my own Decoding function, but this doesn't even update parent properties. Children stay same though

https://play.golang.org/p/lswJJY0yl80

Expected:

> result:[{A:1 Children:[{B:11}]} {A:2 Children:[{B:22}]}]

Actual:

> result:[{A:init Children:[{B:22}]} {A:init Children:[{B:22}]}]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023943/update-array-elements-if-the-array-in-passed-as-val-and-then-converted-to-inter#answer-57024131 for a generic function that decodes a mongo cursor to a slice of any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're decoding into the same pointer, so you'll always end up with a slice containing elements whose value is the same as the one you decoded last.

You should instead, on each iteration, initialize a new instance of the model's type and then decode into that.

```
result, _ := mongodb.Search(store.Time{}, ...) // pass in non-pointer type to make life easier

// ...

func Search(model interface{}, filter interface{}) (result ModelCollection, err error) {
    collection := Database.Collection(resolveCollectionName(model))

    var cursor *mongo.Cursor
    cursor, err = collection.Find(Context, filter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } 

    for cursor.Next(Context) {
        v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(model)).Interface() // get a new pointer instance
        if err := cursor.Decode(v); err != nil { // decode
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        md := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Interface()
        result = append(result, md) // append non-pointer value
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(model)).Interface()` was exactly what i was missing. Was trying different ways of simple assignment like `tmp := model`.

Still can't get it working though. When looping through result type assertion doesn't work: `if time, ok := v.(store.Time); ok {` is false.

I guess I will switch to cursor implementation and return a cursor instead of result array. This way no "reflect" is needed at all

Comment: Figured out that return array is a list of pointers, so correct type assert should look: `if time, ok := v.(*store.Time); ok {`

Comment: Did you pass in a pointer to `Search` or a non-pointer? Before appending to result did you call the `Elem` method on `reflect.ValueOf(v)` or not?

Comment: Passing a pointer. 

Before appending calling `reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Interface()`. Full code: `v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(model)).Interface()
  if err := cursor.Decode(v); err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
  }
  modelDeref := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Interface()
  result = append(result, modelDeref)`

Comment: that's the problem then, reflect.New returns a pointer to a value of the given type, which if it is a pointer already, will result in a pointer to a pointer. You don't need to pass in a pointer, but if you want to then you should call `reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(model).Elem()).Interface()`.